# Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_4,\sqrt[4]{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p-1$ not divisible by $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p > 2$ be a prime number such that $p-1$ is not divisible by $4$.

Consider $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{p},\zeta_4)$ where $\zeta_4 \in L$ is a primitive forth root of unity (i.e. roots of the polynomial $x^2 +1 \in K[x]$). If my arguments are correct, the extension $L/K$ is Galois and has degree $8$.

> **Question**: What is the Galois group of $L/K$?

I know that $F=K(\zeta_4)$ is the maximal unramified subextension of $L/K$ with degree $2$. I think this is probably how I should approach this problem. I have the feeling that I could show that the Galois group is not the cyclic group of order $8$ but I am not sure how the argument works.

Comment: If $L/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is abelian then $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/4})$ is Galois so that $i$ is in $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $4 |p-1$.

Comment: If $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ (or just not of characteristic $2$, $x^4 - a$ is irreducible in $K[x]$, and $\zeta_4 \not\in K(\sqrt{a})$, then the splitting field of $x^4-a$ over $K$ is $L := K(\sqrt[4]{a},\zeta_4)$ and ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ is dihedral of order $8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_4)$. By Kummer theory we have that $L$ is Galois over $F$ and $\text{Gal}(L/F) = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $\sigma \mapsto \frac{\sigma\sqrt[4]{p}}{ \sqrt[4]{p}}$ (which is independent of the choice of 4th root).

So we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to  0.
$$
It follows that $G$ is either the Dihedral group of order 8 or is abelian. But $G$ is not abelian since the subextension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[4]{p})$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you maybe elaborate on the argument why $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[4]{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ not being Galois implies that $G$ is not abelian?

Comment: If a group is abelian, then in particular all its subgroups are normal. So if a Galois group is abelian, then all subfields of the field are also Galois over the base (since normal subgroups correspond to Galois subextensions under the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Another question: Why can we exclude the case that $G$ is the Quarternion group? It is non-abelian, also has order $8$ and normal subgroup $C_4$ with corresponding quotient $C_2$.

Comment: @Ribbity By basic Galois theory $G$ can be seen a group of permutations of the four roots of $x^4-p$. That is, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$. By Sylow theory (or more direct computations) a subgroup of $S_4$ that has order $8$ must be the dihedral group $D_4$ of symmetries of a square.